# Insert text into any arbitrary textbox-like element (not necessarily simple HTML) on page using Javascript in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, textbox

I'm trying to create a Chrome Extension that allows a user to press a keyboard shortcut and have a visual keyboard appear near the textbox they're currently editing.

Currently, when the user presses the shortcut, I check if there is an active element that is a textbox using the following snippet:

```js
/* Get the active textbox on the window, ie. the one with the blinking cursor the user is typing in */
function get_active_textbox() {
    let activeElement = document.activeElement;

    // Is there an active element, and if so, is it of type `text`? Other types of active elements could be checkboxes
    // or radio buttons
    if (activeElement && activeElement.type === "text") {
        return activeElement;
    }
}
```

Once I have the textbox, I can easily insert my text into it. This works perfectly for normal textboxes, but not situations where the textbox is a little more... complicated... such as a draft in Google Inbox:

```html
<div id="S2lLHf-0" tabindex="0" jsaction="blur:quickCompose9.quick_compose_handle_blur;input:quickCompose9.quick_compose_handle_input;focus:quickCompose9.quick_compose_focus" aria-label="Reply to all" jstcache="3148" class="aV editable" g_editable="true"
  role="textbox" contenteditable="true" style="direction: ltr;">this is some text</div>
```

or the compose box in Facebook Messenger:

```html
<div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_6" aria-describedby="js_0" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Type a message..." class="notranslate _5rpu" contenteditable="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="true" tabindex="0" style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;">
  <div data-contents="true">
    <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="75li5" data-offset-key="6h8f0-0-0">
      <div data-offset-key="6h8f0-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="6h8f0-0-0"><span data-text="true">this is some text</span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a more general purpose solution that would allow me to find and insert text into any arbitrary textbox-like element on a page?

Comment: Yes, focus the `[contenteditable="true"]` element and use document.execCommand with 'insertText' or 'insertHTML'

Comment: This doesn't work for plain <input> tags or things such as the Google Search box. It looks like the author of the page needs to explicitly mark the field as editable. Is there a more robust solution?

Comment: execCommand works with any editable element, including inputs on Google Search page. Just make sure the element is focused.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific -- my issue is not with the execCommand. If have the input field located, that works perfectly -- thanks for the suggestion on that. However, I want my dialog (that ends up calling execCommand) to only appear on input-like objects. The contenteditable attribute is not "true" on all editable objects, such as the Google search input and I cannot make that determination. I'm looking for a more robust solution here.

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/athn7ju2/3/). The first input does not have the contenteditable attribute set, and I cannot determine that it's any different than an arbitrary DOM element.

Comment: Simply check element.tagName === 'INPUT' && /^(text|number|search|url)$/i.test(element.type)

Comment: Unfortunately that returns false with the Facebook messenger input field or a Google Inbox draft. Would it be a safe assumption that the [tagName + element.type] check **or** the contenteditable attribute will be true if an element is a text field?

Comment: Judging by the code snippets in your question both use a div with contenteditable attribute so it's trivial to detect. I still don't see the problem. Simply check for the two conditions. AFAIK it covers 100% of cases.